# How to add shadow effect on left, right and bottom sides of background image

Tags: html, css

how might I add a shadow effect on a background image, using CSS ? I would like to have a shadow on the left, right and bottom of the background image ?

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Simply put, show us your own effort.

Answer (score 0):

The command to add the shadow is the "box-shadow". But you can use this site to do this automatically for you:

https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

There's a really handy tool that may help you here https://cssgenerator.org/box-shadow-css-generator.html.

This is an example of a shadow that appears in the areas you mentioned

`box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);`

I've made an example for you:

```css
.shadow {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://placekitten.com/640/360);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I knew about box shadow but what I am referring too is adding a shadow effect on the image it self on the left right and bottom

Comment: @DwayneJones do you have an example of where you've seen this somewhere else so that i know what you mean?

Comment: yes I do how I can I show you I can post pictures here

Comment: Hi @DwayneJones, you could share a link to another website?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px #888 inset
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Refer inset property of box-shadow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#Values